# Collect files using find

Tags: find, scripting

I currently have this script:

```
find . -name '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf $file
```

To collect all the "*.log" files. I would like to modify it to include also all the ".txt" files but I don't know how, this should be fairly simple right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `-regex` flag instead of `-name` you can specify the name as a regular expression:

```
find . -regex '.*\.\(log\|txt\)' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf $file
```

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of ways to change your find command.  Here is one:

```
find . \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*.txt' \) -print0
```

The `-o` is an OR operator, thus if the first condition fails, the second condition is checked.  If you have GNU find, you can also use the aptly named `-or`.  Note that the second expression is not evaluated if the first holds.

Comment: What does the `-o` does?

Comment: @OscarRyz: See my update.

Comment: I'm only getting the .txt files.  :( Thanks anyway +1

Comment: Oh, this is better than mine; I didn't know about `-o`. @OscarRyz It works for me, I get both

Comment: @Michael: When I remove the `-print0` etc. etc, it prints everything, but when I run the full version, the tar.gz file doesn't contain any .log file

Comment: @OscarRyz Oh, I didn't test it with the full expression. I think Gilles just fixed it, you need parentheses or it interprets as `-name '*.log' -o ( -name '*.txt' -print0 )`

Comment: Yeap, that worked, I have +1'ed but to be fair, I'll leave Michael answer as accepted for I have already sent the  .tar.gz file via email  long ago :) :)